# VB6 + componentone developed application in Windows7

Tags: vb6, windows-7, componentone

This is trouble shooting question.

Our application's development environment is VS2005 C/C++, VB6 based GUI.

we use also componentone for ActiveX control(vsflexgrid8).

application performed well in Windows XP, but in Windows 7, there is some problem in GUI.

rebuilded almost all C/C++ code and VB6 code in Windows 7

- our build system is so poor and because I joined this team a month ago, building all codes are a bit hard
- But this (maybe) last problem is not related to build, I think.

all other processes and GUI process are start well. but when click some menu in GUI, all user controls become invalid.

error message seems like this:

> '-2147417848 (80010108)' occured
>   runtime error.
>
> Automation error.
>
> Invoked Object disconnected from
>   client.

above message is not identical to real message since real message is our native language(Korean).

when googling with this message, I'm able to gather some informations.

the most possible case is when using OLE Automation for Microsoft Office Objects.

But our GUI(VB6 developed) does not use Microsoft Office Objects.

And problem-causing page/control's are commonly use componentone modules.

So, if experienced similar problems, please help me.

In Virtual Machine Windows XP mode, there is no problem. But I'm strongly willing to develop in this environment.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Automation Error' just means that an error was raised from within the ActviveX control, but that the developpers did not add a description to it. So the cause could be anything.
 A common source for this kind of errors are write errors to protected folder (The Program Files folder for instance) or forbidden Registry Read/Write actions. You could try installing the program to another location or to run it elevated.

Hope this helps at least a little.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar to VB6 or UI programs yet and further I have some works must be done until next week. so this trial will be delayed

Answer (score 0):

As Dabbler says, this means there has been an error in the ActiveX component.

- Does any of your C or C++ code run before this error happens?
- Are you using the latest version of the ComponentOne control? Perhaps it's worth checking whether it is supported on Windows 7, and contacting their technical support?
- You could debug the VB6 and C/C++ on Windows 7 to track down which bit of code triggers this problem. This is possible with Visual  Studio 2005, which you say you have, or WinDbg which is free.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by Windows Updates.

Since about 20~30 updates are performed at once, I can't know what update solves this.

I guess Visual Studio 2005 security updates may the reason for this trouble.

Anyway, my application runs well in my Windows 7 machine.

Thanks to All.